# Optimize ABCpdf file size

Tags: pdf-generation, filesize, abcpdf

We've got a web system that generates dynamic pdf files with ABCpdf.  While it works... okay, the file sizes are a little large.

For example, this morning as a test I generated a 140+ page file with lots of little graphics (actually, the same six little images repeated over and over.)  The total file size was 12 megs and change.

Taking that file, opening it in Acrobat Pro and running it through the default optimization settings got me a 600k file.

Does anyone have any suggestions for getting the original file a little closer to that second number?

Answer (score 2):

This is almost guaranteed to be an image compression issue.

[PixMap](http://abcupload.com/helppdf7net/source/6-abcpdf6.objects/pixmap/1-methods/compressjpeg.htm) provides JPEG compression of underlying images. It's possible to actually have the software uncompress JPEGs that you've inserted and have it store as a Bitmap, and that would easily bloat the size.

Also ensure that your sizing is correct - don't include a 1600x1200 image and have it show in a tiny 2" frame - you can resize/scale it down in that case.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried the latest version of ABCpdf? You should find this particular issue has been fixed ;-)

Answer (score 0):

ABCpdf appears to have many options for embedding images. Which did you use? What size are your images? What format? How many per page?

You may have some luck making your images smaller, either lower resolution or a better compression format (i.e. JPEG).

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like ABCpdf may be repeating the images rather than inserting each of them once into the PDF and referencing them.  You could try [CosEdit](http://www.pdftron.com/cosedit/index.html) to see if that is the case.  If it is you will get a lot of stream objects, whereas optimised output would have lots of references to the same few stream objects.

Answer (score 0):

You could also try running pdf compression over the top of the new files, if you cant get the abcPdf settings right.

See [pdftk compression option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5296667/pdftk-compression-option) for how to do this in c#.